# Android RecyclerView: How to avoid scroll interruption(scroll twice) when scroll state is not IDLE?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to avoid RecyclerView being scrolled when the scrollState is not IDLE ?

I have tried some ideas like overriding `canScrollHorizontally()` in my `LinearLayoutManager` and return `false` when `scrollState != IDLE` or same concept applied to `dispatchTouchEvent()` in `Activity`, but it will just stuck the screen forever.

I also tried an Asyntask method but the while loop made it never escape doInBackground and go to onPostExercute:

```
 @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (previousScrollState != 0) {

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        while (previousScrollState != 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground " + previousScrollState);
                        }

                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        recList.setTouchEnabled(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
                        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                        recList.setTouchEnabled(true);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute " + previousScrollState);
                    }
                }.execute();

            }

            previousScrollState = newState;
}
```

My purpose is to avoid user to skip any page(scroll twice or more at the same time). How can I achieve it? Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a bad solution but before a better answer come out:

```
 @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (previousScrollState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                if (asyncCheckScrollState == null || asyncCheckScrollState.isCancelled()) {

                    asyncCheckScrollState = new AsyncCheckScrollState();
                    asyncCheckScrollState.execute();

                }
            }

        // ...

        previousScrollState = newState;
}
```

And:

```
public class AsyncCheckScrollState extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        recList.setTouchEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            while (previousScrollState != 0) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "canceled ");
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            this.cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        recList.setTouchEnabled(true);
    }
}
```